# Size of data: '{0}' and Proxy response returned error: '{0}'

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

During backup I have following error:

`10/18/2016 11:40:32.17  w3wp.exe (0x14FF0)                          0x1010C SharePoint Foundation           Asp Runtime                     aj1kl   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 10/18/2016 11:40:32.06, Original Level: Verbose] SPRequestModule.PreRequestExecuteAppHandler   6c95ae9d-0a6b-7029-a2e9-d4ca9e11c48e
10/18/2016 11:40:32.17  w3wp.exe (0x14FF0)                          0x1010C SharePoint Foundation           Asp Runtime                     aj1kp   High        [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] SPRequestModule.PreSendRequestHeaders  6c95ae9d-0a6b-7029-a2e9-d4ca9e11c48e
10/18/2016 11:40:32.17  w3wp.exe (0x14FF0)                          0x1010C SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Monitorable Micro Trace Tags: (none)    6c95ae9d-0a6b-7029-a2e9-d4ca9e11c48e
10/18/2016 11:40:32.17  w3wp.exe (0x14FF0)                          0x65A4  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              advu2   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 10/18/2016 11:40:32.04, Original Level: Verbose] Size of data: '{0}' bytes 6c95ae9d-0a6b-7029-a2e9-d4ca9e11c48e
10/18/2016 11:40:32.17  w3wp.exe (0x14FF0)                          0x65A4  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              aa0al   High        [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: High] Proxy response returned error: '{0}'  6c95ae9d-0a6b-7029-a2e9-d4ca9e11c48e`